# Removing Special Characters using SUM(IF(ISERROR) in Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to do [what this guy did in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051731/search-a-cell-for-specific-special-characters-and-color-the-cell-red-if-found) - Get the errors using SUM(IF(ISERROR) But I don't need to format it after that - I need to remove those special characters.

I need to remove special characters from a column that has 266 records. I use Excel 2003 so the SUBSTITUTE can't be used for Nesting more than 8 levels.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the same set of special characters that were in the other question, or a different list of special characters?

Comment: Why didn't you follow up on the question [you already had](http://superuser.com/questions/880598/excel-sumifiserror-function)?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same list of special characters, you don't need to nest the formulas too many times.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"`",""),"'",""),"""",""),"/",""),"\",""),"^","")
```